# Nokia router G-2425G-A maximum theoretical and practical speed over 5Ghz wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, internet-speed

I have an internet connection (ISP Airtel) that promises a bandwidth of 1 Gbps. Over ethernet, I see a bandwidth of around 900 Mbps, however, over wifi 5Ghz, the maximum speed I receive is 450-470 Mpbs (with Macbook Pro 2019) under the best possible conditions.
The router provided by ISP is Nokia G-2425G-A. Is it some limitation of the router? I could not find any documentation regarding theoretical and practical speed on this router.
Can someone help me identify the root cause of this degradation over wifi?

Comment: Sounds like good 11ac 2×2 speeds. The Wi-Fi client is also very relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Wi-Fi certification](https://www.wi-fi.org/product-finder-results?sort_by=certified&sort_order=desc&keywords=G-2425G-B), your router has Wi-Fi 5 (11ac) with 2 spatial streams. That means it supports gross bandwidths of up to 866.7 MBit/s.

However, because Wi-Fi is not a full-duplex transport (unlike Ethernet), you cannot expect these bandwidths with user data. That’s because there’s always some data being sent back (ACK packets, …). You’ll get slightly more than half the gross bandwidth in day-to-day use. Which is exactly what you’re seeing.

If you want faster speeds, you can go for Wi-Fi 6 (11ax). However, unless your clients can also do it, nothing will change. Your MacBook does not support Wi-Fi 6.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, however, are you aware of what is the wifi certification (max wifi speed) for MacBook pro 2019, I could not find this info

Comment: It’s apparently not certified at all. It supports Wi-Fi 5 3×3 (up to 1300 MBit/s). So you can get more speed with a router that supports 3 spatial streams.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small correction to Daniel's reply. In the above Answer Wi-Fi certification is not for [G-2425G-A](https://www.wi-fi.org/product-finder-results?sort_by=certified&sort_order=desc&keywords=G-2425G-A) it is taking to G-2425G-B instead.